# How do I correctly structure an NSPredicate to create an array of values from CoreData objects with a specific date tag?

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to grab values from CoreData objects entered on a specific date.  I have found a number of somewhat similar questions on SO and other sites and have messed around extensively and cobbled together code that seems like it should work, but it is not returning any values for data that I know is there. I am a relative beginner so basic responses are appreciated.  Code below.  Sorry if this is overkill but I'm not sure where the breakdown is.  Thanks in advance.

```
 @IBAction func plusDayToEdit(_ sender: Any) {
    if dayToEdit < 30 {
        dayToEdit += 1
        dayToEditLabel.text = String(dayToEdit)
        previousDayFetchRequest()
    } else {

    }

func previousDayFetchRequest() {

guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Entry")

var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local

let dateToEdit = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: (0 - dayToEdit), to: Date())
let startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: dateToEdit!)
let endDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)

let fromPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "entryDate <= %@", startDate as NSDate)
let toPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "entryDate > %@", endDate! as NSDate)
let dateToEditPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [fromPredicate, toPredicate])

fetchRequest.predicate = dateToEditPredicate
```

Comment: `fromPredicate` searches before `startDate` and `toPredicate` searches after `endDate`. Switch `<=` and `>`.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing.  Much appreciated.